# Capturar el ID de mi tabla por medio del jcombobox

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Alimento de varias formas mi jcombobox pero al capturar el dato no me funciona con este codigo lleno el cbo:

public void llenarproveedor(JComboBox cboxprov ) {

```
String[] registros = new String[2];   
DefaultComboBoxModel llenar = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
llenar.addElement("Seleccione un NIT");
cboxprov.setModel(llenar);
        sSQL = "SELECT id_proveedor, nit FROM tproveedores ORDER BY id_proveedor";

 try {
        PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sSQL);

        while (rs.next()) {
            registros[0] = rs.getString("id_proveedor");
            registros[1] = rs.getString("nit");
            llenar.addElement(rs.getString(2));             
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    } finally{
     if(cn!=null){
         try{
             cn.close();
         }catch (SQLException ex){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);      
         }
     }
 }

}
```

E intentado capturar el con un evento en el CBO de esta manera para guardarla en una caja de texto pero no lo hace:

private void JCBproveedoresItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {

```
   Tproveedor sprov = (Tproveedor)JCBproveedores.getSelectedItem();
    if (JCBproveedores.getSelectedItem() == "id_proveedor") 
        idproveedor.setText("");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si pruebas con un `getSelectedIndex`?

Este seria el código:

```
  Tproveedor sprov = (Tproveedor)JCBproveedores.getSelectedItem();
    if (JCBproveedores.getSelectedIndex().equals"id_proveedor") 
        idproveedor.setText("");
```

Si no me equivoco seria solo un `=` y no dos `==`.